# How to create star shaped graph on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to create star shaped graph using single "CREATE" statement of CYPHER.

How to create star shaped graph on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use variable on first cypher pattern, and reuse variable on following cypher patterns.

```
agens=# create (n:v{id:1})-[:e]->(:v{id:2}), 
               (n)-[:e]->(:v{id:3}), 
               (n)-[:e]->(:v{id:4});

GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 4, INSERT EDGE 3)
agens=# match p = (n:v{id:1})-[:e]->() return p;
                          p                          
-----------------------------------------------------
 [v[3.1]{"id": 1},e[4.1][3.1,3.2]{},v[3.2]{"id": 2}]
 [v[3.1]{"id": 1},e[4.2][3.1,3.3]{},v[3.3]{"id": 3}]
 [v[3.1]{"id": 1},e[4.3][3.1,3.4]{},v[3.4]{"id": 4}]
(3 rows)
```